# There is no row at position 0.

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm creating a web page where the user can edit information in the `DataGrid` but I keep getting this error:

> Exception Details: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: There is no row at
>   position 0.

This is my code :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label lblProj = this.Master.FindControl("lblProj") as Label;
    Label lblStr = this.Master.FindControl("lblStruct") as Label;
    if (Session["projCode"] == null && Session["structCode"] == null)
    {
        Response.Redirect("frmSignIn.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        FillGrid();
        lblProj.Text = cbal.getField("Project_View", "@PrjM_id_int", Session["projCode"].ToString(), "NameByCode");
        string[,] paramVal = new string[2, 2];
        paramVal[0, 0] = "@sd_Code_var";
        paramVal[0, 1] = Session["structCode"].ToString();
        paramVal[1, 0] = "@Sd_ProjectCode_var";
        paramVal[1, 1] = Session["projCode"].ToString();
        DataSet ds = cbal.fillGrid_with_param("Structure_Definition_GetStrctureName", paramVal);
        lblStr.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["STRUCTURE NAME"].ToString();
    }
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        FillContQuot();
        FillContractor();
    }
  // drpContractorName.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(drpContractorName_SelectedIndexChanged);
} 

protected void drpContractorName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CQRA"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tbl_Contractor_Master where CNT_Code_var =' " + drpContractorName.SelectedValue.ToString() + " '", conn);
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    int count = 0;
    Label1.Visible = true;
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        count++;
    }
    if (count > 0)
    {
        Label1.Text = "This Contractor Not Available";
    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Text = "This Contractor Already Exist";
    }
    //Label1.Visible = false;
}

private void FillContractor()
{
    string[,] paramVal2 = new string[1, 2];
    paramVal2[0, 0] = "@CNT_Id_int";
    paramVal2[0, 1] = "-1";
    DataSet ds = cbal.fillGrid_with_param("Contractor_Master_view", paramVal2);
    Dictionary<string, string> dct = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    dct.Add("0", "Select");
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            dct.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["CONTRACTOR CODE"].ToString(), ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["CONTRACTOR NAME"].ToString());
        }
    }
    drpContractorName.DataSource = dct;
    drpContractorName.DataValueField = "Key";
    drpContractorName.DataTextField = "Value";
    drpContractorName.DataBind();
}   

private void FillContQuot()
{
    string[,] paramVal2 = new string[1, 2];
    paramVal2[0, 0] = "@CQ_ID_int";
    paramVal2[0, 1] = "-1";
    DataSet ds = cbal.fillGrid_with_param("contract_Quotaionapply", paramVal2);
    Dictionary<string, string> dct = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    dct.Add("0", "Select");
    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        dct.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString(), ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString());
    }
    drpConQuot.DataSource = dct;
    drpConQuot.DataValueField = "Key";
    drpConQuot.DataTextField = "Value";
    drpConQuot.DataBind();
}    
protected void DrpConQuotSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblMsg.Text = "";
    if (drpConQuot.SelectedIndex != 0)
    {
        FillGrid();
        btnsave.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        grdQuotation.DataSource = null;
        grdQuotation.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void DrpContractorNameSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbCQRA@12Sept2012TGConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tbl_Contractor_Master where CNT_Code_var =' " + drpContractorName.SelectedValue.ToString() + " '", conn);
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    int count = 0;
    Label1.Visible = true;
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        count++;
    }
    if (count > 0)
    {
        Label1.Text = "Not Available";
    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Text = "Available";
    }
}

private void FillGrid()
{
    string[,] param = new string[1,2];
    Dictionary<string, string> key = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    //item.Clear();
    key.Add("0", "--Select--");
    param[0, 0] = "@Quotation_code_Var";
    try
    {
        param[0, 1] = drpConQuot.SelectedItem.Value;
    }
    catch
    {
        param[0, 1] = "";
    }
    dsQuot = cbal.fillGrid_with_param("Quotation_Comparision", param);
    if (dsQuot.Tables.Count <= 0)
        return;
    DataTable tab = new DataTable();
    tab.Columns.Add("ITEM NAME");
    for (int i = 0; i < dsQuot.Tables.Count; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            tab.Columns.Add(dsQuot.Tables[i].Rows[0]["Contractor"].ToString().Split('/')[0]);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblMsg.Text = ex.Message.ToString();
        }
    }
    foreach (DataRow r1 in dsQuot.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
         DataRow r = tab.NewRow();
         //for (int i = 0; i < r1.ItemArray.Length - 1; i++)
         r[0] = r1[0].ToString();
         tab.Rows.Add(r);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < dsQuot.Tables.Count; i++)
    {
        int c = 0;
        foreach (DataRow r1 in dsQuot.Tables[i].Rows)
        {
            tab.Rows[c][i+1] = r1[1].ToString();
            c++;
        }
    }
    grdQuotation.DataSource = tab;       
    grdQuotation.DataBind();
}

protected void Btnsaveclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
                string cotationno = drpConQuot.SelectedValue;
                string quot_AwardedTo = drpContractorName.SelectedValue;//(r.Cells[r.Cells.Count - 2].FindControl("ddlName") as DropDownList).SelectedValue;
                string[,] para = new string[2, 2];
                para[0, 0] = "@quot_no_int";
                para[1, 0] = "@quot_AwardedTo";
                para[0, 1] = cotationno;
                para[1, 1] = quot_AwardedTo;
                cbal.fillGrid_with_param("Contract_AwardedTo", para);
                lblMsg.Text = "Records Saved!";
    }
    catch(Exception e1)
    {
        lblMsg.Text = e1.Message;
    }
}

protected void GridView1RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if your DataSet have Rows.

```
if(DataSet.Tables[0].rows.Count > 0 )
{
// your Code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When ever you're using `DataSet` you need the check `ds.table[0].rows.count > 0` than you need the write your required code

```
DataSet ds = cbal.fillGrid_with_param("Contractor_Master_view", paramVal2);
```

Comment: Thnks.I got the solution.Actually I was missing  to check the rowcount